# Christ and the Believer Icon (Companion Icon) origin?

Tags: origin, iconography

I was in [Taize](https://shop.taize.fr/) and besides finding it to be a rather interesting place, I found a lot of refreshing symbols there. Particularly the (based on Taize page) Christ and the Believer Icon (or the companion icon translated to my language):

[image: Christ and the Believer Icon]

I always found it quite inspiring (and I assumed it was an orthodox icon), but I found it rather hard to find documentation about it. Besides some theological and iconographic debates around it that describes it as being Christ with someone that can be any of us, as the name suggests.

Does anyone know the origin/history of this icon? Or any official source for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Christ and the Believer Icon (Companion Icon) origin?**

[image: Icon of Friendship]

[Icon of Friendship](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Icon_of_friendship_luwr.jpg) as it is commonly called goes by a few similar titles.

This is a 6 century Coptic icon from Bawit, Egypt of Christ and [Saint Mina](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Menas). Its’ author is unknown and is one of the oldest known icons in existence. It can be viewed at the Louvre, where it is now on display.